# File upload for Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, updatepanel

I have the following code

```
<asp:Content ID="headContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<asp:DynamicDataManager ID="DynamicDataManager1" runat="server" AutoLoadForeignKeys="true">
    <DataControls>
        <asp:DataControlReference ControlID="FormView1" />
    </DataControls>
</asp:DynamicDataManager>
<h2 class="DDSubHeader">
    Edit entry from table
    <%= table.DisplayName %></h2>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" EnableClientScript="true"
            HeaderText="List of validation errors" CssClass="DDValidator" />
        <asp:DynamicValidator runat="server" ID="DetailsViewValidator" ControlToValidate="FormView1"
            Display="None" CssClass="DDValidator" />
        <asp:FormView runat="server" ID="FormView1" DataSourceID="DetailsDataSource" DefaultMode="Edit"
            OnItemCommand="FormView1_ItemCommand" OnItemUpdated="FormView1_ItemUpdated" RenderOuterTable="false"
            OnPageIndexChanging="FormView1_PageIndexChanging">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <table id="detailsTable" class="DDDetailsTable" cellpadding="6">
                    <asp:DynamicEntity runat="server" Mode="Edit" />
                    <tr class="td">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                        <td>





                            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server">
                            </asp:Label>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" Text="Upload" />







                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <div class="DDNoItem">
                    No such item.</div>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
        <asp:LinqDataSource ID="DetailsDataSource" runat="server" EnableUpdate="true" />
        <asp:QueryExtender TargetControlID="DetailsDataSource" ID="DetailsQueryExtender"
            runat="server">
            <asp:DynamicRouteExpression />
        </asp:QueryExtender>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This file was generate using Dynamic Data. I am trying to add a file upload control in the form but in the code behind I can't acces 'FileUpload1' to see if it contains elements.
How can I do that?

If I make a new form it works but I can't get it out to work in my existing form.

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server"></form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common issue.
You are trying to upload file on ajax request calling upload from update panel.
But you need full postback to upload it using serious FileUpload or look for javascript based file upload controls.

Comment: But I'm only trying to acces FileUpload1   element from code behind and it isn't recognized. What has to be with Ajax?

Comment: You can access but the data you try to upload would not reach your server if it is ajax query. It's ajax request restriction.

Comment: Ok. I see the problem now. Thank you. I'll search for an alternate solution